# How to calculate the element-wise minimum of multiple matrices?

Tags: matrix, dolphindb

I'm working with multiple M x N matrices in DolphinDB. I want to calculate the maximum/minimum values of elements with the same index across these matrices and return a M x N matrix.

For minimum values, I'd like to ignore NULL values unless all values with the same index are NULL.

Can anyone share some best practices for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following script:

```
n = matrix(1 1 1, 5 5 5)
n2 = matrix(10 11 12, 00 -5 -5)
n3 = matrix(-1 1 00, -3 00 10)
min:E join:T:E:E [n,n2,n3]
// each(min, reduce(each{each{join}}, [n,n2,n3]))
```

The logic is to iteratively extract elements with the same index from each matrix's columns, combine the elements into separate columns and then calculate the minimum value for each column.